# MySQL always writes simple temporary/memory tables to disk (both tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size are set to 8GB)

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.5, windows, memory

I'm struggling with this issue and just can't figure out why this is happening.

```
CREATE TABLE sitecache._test ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT * FROM website.gallery_likes WHERE 1=0;
```

Every time I execute this query, the **Created tmp disk tables** server variable increases immediately by **5**. The same thing happens for `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...` and also for creating a table with a structure definition instead of copying the structure from another table.

Structure of *website.gallery_likes*:

```
CREATE TABLE gallery_likes (
  photoid mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  userid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  timestamp int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY photoid (photoid,userid)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

As you can see there's no TEXT and no BLOB fields, it's a fairly simple table. If I then dump a large set of data into that temporary/memory table, it takes several minutes to complete and I can see how mysqld is writing a lot of data to a temporary file in the C:\Windows\Temp directory.

**tmp_table_size** and **max_heap_table_size** are both set to 8GB (and confirmed via SHOW VARIABLES).

MySQL 5.6.17 x64 on Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 with 64GB RAM.

Config:

```
[client]
no-beep
port=3306

[mysql]
default-character-set=latin1

[mysqld_safe]
open-files-limit=16384

[mysqld]
log-bin="D:/MySQL Blackhole/master_replication.log"
sync_binlog=0
binlog-do-db=...
binlog-ignore-db=...
...edited...
binlog-format=STATEMENT
expire_logs_days=1
server-id=1
ft_min_word_len=3
innodb_ft_min_token_size=3
port=3306
datadir="D:/MySQL/data/"
character-set-server=latin1
default-storage-engine=MYISAM
sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=NONE
general-log=0
general_log_file="MYSQL_SERVER.log"
slow-query-log=0
slow_query_log_file="MYSQL_SERVER-slow.log"
long_query_time=10
log-error="MYSQL_SERVER.err"
max_connections=1024
query_cache_size=0
table_open_cache=4096
tmp_table_size=8G
max_heap_table_size=8G
thread_cache_size=64
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=256M
key_buffer_size=8192M
read_buffer_size=2M
read_rnd_buffer_size=128M
sort_buffer_size=8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=32M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=32G
innodb_log_file_size=8G
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=0
innodb_open_files=4096
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=strict_crc32
innodb_adaptive_hash_index=ON
back_log=80
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=8M
max_allowed_packet=16M
max_connect_errors=10
open_files_limit=16384
query_cache_type=0
table_definition_cache=2500
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
```

(`query_cache_size=0` and `default-storage-engine=MYISAM` on purpose)

This happens on the production system. I have MySQL 5.6.16 x64 on my development machine (Windows 8.1 x64) running with the exact same databases and almost the same config (smaller innodb buffer pool, tmp_table_size at 512M, no replication) and this doesn't happen here. Something environmental must be different.

I've now read the documentation multiple times but I just don't see any connection as to why this happens. The table is fairly simple with no columns that are more than 512 bytes long.
Full disclosure: I already posted it on StackOverflow but nobody responded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in case anyone stumbles upon a similar problem and Google directs them here:
I don't exactly figured out why, but sort of figured out what causes it, **phpMyAdmin** was the culprit.

Issuing the same commands directly in the mysql command line did not cause the temporary tables to be written to disk.
Now, I also have phpMyAdmin on my development machine and it's not an issue here. But I'm running PHP as a module in Apache, whereas on the production server it's IIS with PHP running as FastCGI. So some configuration or limitation must've caused this, not exactly sure.

Comment: Great that you got to the bottom of it - or at least managed to eliminate MySQL. Don't forget to mark your own answer as correct (don't think you can do it immediately though). BTW, welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I tried to mark my own answer, but it told me to wait 2 days. Will come back to do so :)